# BS4 - descendants returns empty, despite it is wrong

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

everyone.
I have the following code:

```
for child in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():        
    if child.name == 'div':
        root = soup.find("div",id="app")
        print(root)
        root_childs = [e for e in root.descendants]
        print(root_childs)
```

It returns

```
<div id="app"></div>
[]
```

But the webpage has this structure:

[image]

I want to get into this APP thing, but I can't. What could be the problem? Thank you

Comment: add the html source code not an image .

Comment: I want to parse this page 5ka.r u/sp ecial_off ers/